# Connect Outlook to google apps

Tags: outlook, synchronization, google-apps

I use outlook 2010 with my Google App account , however , I dont manage to set appointments with my contacts (who are under the same Google App) and invite/see their aviliablily

what shall I do in order to sync Outlook 2010 with Google Apps Calendar/Contacts?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might have just configured Outlook to check your Google Apps via IMAP or POP. This method syncs only your Google Apps email, not calendar or contacts. To get Mail, Calendar and Contacts synced you should install Google Apps Sync for Microsoft Outlook from:

https://tools.google.com/dlpage/gappssync

Jay